# Programatically get statistics for deployments on a domain

Tags: java, glassfish, monitoring

Is there any way to get information specifically about deployments on a glassfish domain? Ideally, heap usage, thread counts, etc. I think this is possible with jconsole and some other visual tools via jmx, but I've never had to attempt such a feat.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically get the server information using JMX. Follow the link below.
http://kalali.me/manage-administrate-and-monitor-glassfish-v3-from-java-code-using-amx-jmx/

Comment: Do you know how you would get information on a specific deployment this way?

Answer (score 1):

I have never had to use this. But there exists a project in Glassfish that provides Java interface to management tools. There is a good article on this here http://kalali.me/manage-administrate-and-monitor-glassfish-v3-from-java-code-using-amx-jmx/

For GlassfishV3 -- the docs are here. http://glassfish.java.net/nonav/v3/admin/planning/V3Changes/V3_AMX_SPI.html

There is some doc available for V2 as well.. I donot find right now.